# Sending a response from an AJAX POST request from PHP back to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a POST request using AJAX, using a proxy to bypass CORS issues and then getting a response from the third party API I am doing a POST request to.

I would like to send the response from PHP to Ajax, however I am not seeing this response in AJAX.

This is how I am making a POST request:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "proxy.php?url=https://***/***",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            console.log('succesful', data)
        }
    });
```

This is how I am bypassing CORS issues in PHP:

```
function makePostRequest($baseURL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = http_build_query($_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
        $json = json_decode($response, true);
        createCookie($json['authToken']);
        echo $json;
        // exit();
    }
}
```

I know I am successfully making a `POST` request, I see the `POST` request in my dev tools network activity, along with the response I expect from this API. However, I am not console.logging the response with AJAX

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @mplungjan no errors

Comment: You shouldn't be decoding the json response and trying to echo that object / array

Comment: Oh @Phil has it, json_decode creates an ARRAY, which is fine for getting your Authtoken. However for the echo, you want to echo the actual json response itself, which is just $response.

Comment: also should URL-encode the value passed to `?url=` param, it likely breaks after the second `?`

Comment: Speaking of the URL being passed, you will probably want to include that in PHP through a variable of sorts instead of passing it via the request then passing it to PHP. You are opening up your proxy to unauthorized usage.